# Is the Clausius statement violated by a non-cyclic isothermal ideal gas expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have read that Kelvin-Planck statement and Clausius statement are equivalent. The problem I have is that Kelvin-Planck statement does not deny the possibility of a non-cyclic process where the net result is complete conversion of heat $Q_H$ into work $W$, like the case of an isothermal ideal gas expansion. Couldn't the output work of that process $W$ be used to run a refrigerator that takes $Q_c$ from a colder reservoir and deliver heat $Q'_H$ at the original hot reservoir where $Q'_H = Q_c + W = Q_c + Q_H$, thus having a net process that violates the Clausius statement even thoough it doesn't violate the Kelvin-Planck statement due to the cyclic requirement of the latter?

Comment: Please clarify your question to show mathematically what violation is claimed to occur. Make sure to include the entropy gain from the one-time expansion.

Comment: *Both* the Clausius and the Kelvin-Planck versions require that the engine operate in a cycle, otherwise you cannot be *sure* that the processes return to a state of "no other changes than"!

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that Kelvin-Planck statement and Clausius statement are
> equivalent.

The Kelvin-Planck statement is: *No heat engine can operate in a cycle while transferring heat with a single reservoir.* The Clausius' statement is: *No refrigeration or heat pump cycle can operate without a net work input.* They are equivalent to the extent that the heat engine cycle becomes a refrigeration or heat pump cycle when operated in reverse. See the Figure below.

> The problem I have is that Kelvin-Planck statement does not deny the
> possibility of a non-cyclic process where the net result is complete
> conversion of heat $Q_H$ into work $W$, like the case of an isothermal
> ideal gas expansion.

What is the problem with that? The statement only applies to a cycle. And the net result *of the cycle* is not the complete conversion of heat $Q_H$ into work $W$ by the isothermal expansion. The net work done in the cycle is the work done by the isothermal expansion minus the work done by the isothermal compression, or equivalently $W=Q_{H}-Q_c$.

> Couldn't the output work of that process $W$ be used to run a
> refrigerator that takes $Q_c$ from a colder reservoir and deliver heat
> $Q'_H$ at the original hot reservoir where $Q'_H = Q_c + W = Q_c +
> > Q_H$,

It appears you are thinking that the net work done by the heat engine cycle is the work done by the isothermal expansion, which it is not. $Q^{'}_{H}=Q_H$ and $W=Q_{H}-Q_c$.

Hope this helps.

[image]